# Synchronisation mechanism without disabling interrupts on Cortex M0

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, synchronization

To clarify a question assume that we have:

1. Static Button object: `static Button_T sButton = {0};`
2. Function to get Button: `void GetButton(Button_T * p_button);` that is called from **main loop context**
3. ISR handler: `void ButtonISRHandler(void);`

Assumptions:

1. `GetButton` execution can be interrupted by any interrupt that does not execute `ButtonISRHandler`
2. `ButtonISRHandler` execution can be interrupted by other iterrupts
3. `GetButton` execution takes less time than the minimum time between two `ButtonISRHandler` interrupts call.
4. Button interrupt is a **cyclic interrupt** triggered for instance every 10 ms.
5. In `ButtonISRHandler` we have procedures like checking button PIN state or detecting if button is touched (in touch button case). If a given PIN state is stable in e.g. for 5 consequtive calls then `sButton` object state is updated.
6. `Button_T` is generic object - it could be classic tact switch or touch button etc.
7. `ScanButtonAndUpdate` could handle a list of Button_T objects but `GetButton` function operates only on the one button object.

The problem is: classic case when an interrupt can occur when program counter is inside `GetButton`

The question is: How to synchronize `GetButton` with `ButtonISRHandler` **without disableing Interrupts**?

My target processor is Cortex M0 without LDREX/STREX operation so I cannot use atomics from C11 that would be great solution in this case.

**My Proposed Solution**

Use Critical Section in `GetButton`.

If an interrupt occured when the program counter is inside Critical Section then do not handle `ScanButtonAndUpdate` in interrupt but handle it on `ExitCriticalSection`. Defer `ScanButtonAndUpdate` execution.

There is no possibility to call `ScanButtonAndUpdate` function from interrupt and main context in the same time - this behaviour is protected by semaphore

**Implementation**

```
#define SEMAPHORE_GIVEN                             0
#define SEMAPHORE_TAKEN                             1

typedef uint32_t BaseType_T;
typedef struct Button_T;

static volatile BaseType_T sSemaphore = SEMAPHORE_GIVEN;
static volatile bool sIsPendingISR = false;
static volatile Button_T sButton = {0};

void GetButton(Button_T * p_button)
{
    EnterCriticalSection();

    memcpy(p_button, &sButton, sizeof(Button_T))
    /* Other procedures on sButton... */

    ExitCriticalSection();
}

/* Cyclic executed handler */
void ButtonISRHandler(void)
{
    if (!BinarySemaphoreTake()) {
        SetISRPending();
    }
    else {
        ScanButtonAndUpdate();

        BinarySemaphoreGive();
    }
}

void ScanButtonAndUpdate(void)
{
    /* Scan for instance a current PIN state and update sButton object
       if state is stable in next calls */
}

static void EnterCriticalSection(void)
{
    while(false == BinarySemaphoreTake()) continue;
}

static void ExitCriticalSection(void)
{
    BinarySemaphoreGive();

    if (IsPendingISR()){
        ScanButtonAndUpdate();
        ResetISRPending();
    }
}

static bool BinarySemaphoreTake(void)
{
    if (SEMAPHORE_GIVEN == sSemaphore) {
        /* Value Store operation is atomic on the architecture native type */
        sSemaphore = SEMAPHORE_TAKEN;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

static void BinarySemaphoreGive(void)
{
    sSemaphore = SEMAPHORE_GIVEN;
}

static void SetISRPending(void)
{
    sIsPendingISR = true;
}

static void ResetISRPending(void)
{
    sIsPendingISR = false;
}

static bool IsPendingISR(void)
{
    return sIsPendingISR;
}
```

This solution was tested and works great without problems but I am not sure that this is the best solution without hidden bugs.

**EDIT 1:** Updated Assumptions and added missing `ScanButtonAndUpdate` function

Comment: Depending on what you have to do for `/* Get button... */` or `/* Update button */` there might be simpler solutions.

Comment: I have edited question to make it clearer @Bodo

Comment: All of this code is just bloat around a simple `volatile bool` flag, which works too. And `Button_T` is clearly nothing your ISR should concern itself about, it should just copy the relevant 32 bit port register. `Button_T` is your interface to the user of your code, don't mix that up with the ISR. I also believe you will be missing interrupts.

Comment: That being said, the simplest solution is just to disable the specific interrupt during access. Why exactly can't you disable buttons for a couple of hundred ns? The interrupt will still be pending and it takes > 10ms before the buttons have stable values anyhow. Your memcpy probably takes around 100 times the time it would take for the caller to copy a single 32 bit variable. Using memcpy inside an ISR for any purpose is almost certainly a bug. If you need to hard copy something you swap 2 pointers instead.

Comment: I'm not that acknowledged about cortex M0, but couldn't you just run two threads of the same priority? One thread would contain GetButton, and the other would start from an ISR. To start execution at the same time, ISR would signal the thread with GetButton just after creating the thread with the ISR button code.

Comment: @Lukali How do you think threads are implemented? With interrupts. Your comment doesn't make any sense. This is low level programming.

Comment: Yes, disabling interrupts is the simplest solution but not the smartest. In the theoretical case when GetButton is called in loop for instance in polling case, then interrupts will be disabled and enabled all the time.

Comment: @Esato - Lundin suggests disabling the *specific* interrupt during access, which is quite standard for many IO techniques, and not at all the same thing as 'disabling interrupts' globally.

Answer (score 2):

There is a hidden synchronization which affects whether you have a race condition or not:  what gates the Interrupt?  The two most common scenarios are edge and level triggered; an edge trigger means that the interrupt will be inhibited until the device is cleared, whereas a level trigger means that the interrupt will repeatedly re-assert until the device is cleared.

If your code uses level triggered interrupts, then you have omitted this synchronization entirely, or you are pretending that sIsPendingISR is the mask & status flag.  In that case, you look alright

If it is level triggered, then it can re-assert during **/* Update sButton object */**, causing the device handling code to be executing in two contexts (interrupt + normal).  Most device code is not designed to do this.

Btw, there is a software protocol called “Dekkers Algorithm” which provides a general solution to mutual exclusion without hardware support.   You have sort of integrated a version of it here.

Comment: Are there even MCUs with level-triggered GPIO? Typically you would rather have a dedicated analog comparator peripheral for that. Though I guess you just provided a nice argument why one should hook up their buttons to an analog comparator instead of edge-triggered GPIO, I never even considered that before.

Comment: @mevets I have added some more assumptions to my question. Interrupt ISR handler is triggered periodically. I have made mistake during preparation of example code. I have separated button interrupt handling to new function ScanButtonAndUpdate.

Comment: Additional to [Dekker''s algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm) there is also the solution from [Peterson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm)

Comment: @Lundin: GPIO interrupts on Atmel SAMD21 and related devices can be configured for edge- and level-triggered operation.

Comment: @Jeremy Isn't that actually using an analog comparator though, through their weird EVSYS mux? Rather than the GPIO peripheral supporting it.

Comment: @Lundin - nope, it's a dedicated edge/level detection stage in the External Interrupt Controller adjunct to the GPIO system.  See http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/SAMD21-Family-DataSheet-DS40001882D.pdf

Comment: @Lundin - I've seen the analog comparator and event system proposed as a way to map GPIO inputs into the event system as asynchronous level-oriented events (because this specific case can't be implemented with the EIC), but for edge- or level-triggered interrupt generation this special case doesn't apply.